# Android: Listview button click event in one row effecting in other rows

Tags: android, listview

I have an '**Approve**' Button in every row of listview. When I click on that 'Approve' button, its Background color should change and text should change from 'Approve' to 'Approved'. Here I am able to write code for this as `setBackgroundColor()`,`setText()`,
but **the problem is,it is also effecting in another rows in the listview,when I am scrolling.** Button color and text of that particular row is also changed. I have tried for this issue from last two days but not found any answer. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

**Here is the code for Adapter Class**

```
public class OrderApprovalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
SessionManager session;
String Wholesaler_name;
String mobile_no,Order_id;
List list1 = new ArrayList();
Context context;

 OrderApprovalDetails contacts;

public OrderApprovalAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull int Resource)
{
    super(context, Resource);
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void add(@Nullable Object object)
{
    super.add(object);
    list1.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return list1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return list1.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final OrderApprovalAdapter.ContactHolder contactHolder;
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    Wholesaler_name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

    View row;
    row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_approval_format, parent, false);
        contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
        contactHolder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.invoice_date);
        contactHolder.orderid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.invoice_no);
        contactHolder.shopname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.shop_name);
        contactHolder.ownername = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
        contactHolder.mobile=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mobile_noo);
        contactHolder.location=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.location);
        contactHolder.itemscount=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.items);
        contactHolder.amount=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.total);
        contactHolder.products_details=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.products);
        contactHolder.Approve=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.approve_btn);

     row.setTag(contactHolder);
    } else
    {
        contactHolder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    final OrderApprovalDetails contacts = (OrderApprovalDetails) this.getItem(position);
    contactHolder.date.setText(contacts.getDate());
    contactHolder.orderid.setText(contacts.getOrderid());
    contactHolder.shopname.setText(contacts.getShopname());
    contactHolder.ownername.setText(contacts.getOwnername());
    contactHolder.mobile.setText(contacts.getMobile());
    contactHolder.location.setText(contacts.getLocation());
    contactHolder.itemscount.setText(contacts.getItemscount());
    contactHolder.amount.setText(contacts.getAmount());
    contactHolder.products_details.setText(contacts.getProducts_details());

    contactHolder.Approve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Approved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         contactHolder.Approve.setEnabled(false);
         contactHolder.Approve.setText("Approved");
         contactHolder.Approve.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
    });
    final View finalRow = row;
    return row;
}
static class ContactHolder
{
    TextView date,orderid,shopname,ownername,mobile,location,itemscount,amount,products_details;
    Button Approve,Decline;
}
```

Comment: try to use position of listview..

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set in Adapter**

```
 String  txtnew = contact.get(position).getOrderid();
```

Comment: Can u please tell me clearly,i couldn't understand  @harshal

Answer (score 0):

you need to set approve(or not) data each time, for all rows. so you need an Array to keep clicked row, like this:

in your adapter:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> selectedPos = new ArrayList<>();
```

in `contactHolder.Approve` onClick:

```
selectedPos.add(position);
```

and finally below this `contactHolder.products_details.setText(contacts.getProducts_details());` line check approve state:

```
 if(selectedPos.contain(position)){
     contactHolder.Approve.setEnabled(false);
     contactHolder.Approve.setText("Approved");
     contactHolder.Approve.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
 } else{
     contactHolder.Approve.setEnabled(true);
     contactHolder.Approve.setText("not Approved");
     contactHolder.Approve.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }
```

Comment: it should, try to use Array of ContactHolder, and add and check this one. for example selectedPos.contain(contactHolder)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

Implement this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this idea:
Take one more field in the database 'status' default 0.
When user click on the Approve button change the status to 1 and according to that update your items in list view something like
if (status==1) then views color,enable/disable etc.